# How do i make my discord bot reactions work after restart with MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have made a command that sends an embed message, and adds reactions which when clicked give/remove a role to a user, everything works, tho after the bot has been restarted the reactions do not work anymore.
I am using MongoDB, I am new to it, I don't know much about using MongoDB, I am also using the compass app.
Now I wanted to somehow make it work with the database so the reactions work even after restart.
(ps: If possible, no need to use a DB).
I also have sort of a ticket command that I have the same issue with.

My current code:

```
    const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'dev-roles',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message.",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        if(message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")){
        const channel = '835948463270264853';
        const JavaScript = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "JavaScript");
        const Java = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Java");
        const HTML = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "HTML");
        const CSS = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "CSS");
        const Python = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Python");
        const PHP = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "PHP");
        const Chash = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "C#");
        const Cpp = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "C++");
        const C = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "C");
 
        const JavaScriptEmoji = '1️⃣';
        const JavaEmoji = '2️⃣';
        const HTMLEmoji = '3️⃣';
        const CSSEmoji = '4️⃣';
        const PythonEmoji = '5️⃣';
        const PHPEmoji = '6️⃣';
        const ChashEmoji = '7️⃣';
        const CppEmoji = '8️⃣';
        const CEmoji = '9️⃣';
 
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#b3e5fc') //#e42643
            .setTitle('DEVELOPER ROLES')
            .setDescription('**ARE YOU A DEV?**\nIf yes, chose the coding languages you know!\nYou will be given acces to coding channels, where you can chat with oher developes, get some help with coding or just help others.\n\n**Note:**\nIf you are not a developer, please **do not** get these roles.\nIf you do so, you may be temporarely / permenantly baned from our server or using our bot.\n\n'
                + `**Reaction Roles:**\n`
                + `${JavaScriptEmoji} - for \`JavaScript\` - <@&834764911103180800>\n`
                + `${JavaEmoji} - for \`Java\` - <@&834764911124414464>\n`
                + `${HTMLEmoji} - for \`HTML\` - <@&834802358525362177>\n`
                + `${CSSEmoji} - for \`CSS\` - <@&834802359674601552>\n`
                + `${PythonEmoji} - for \`Python\` - <@&834764908054577183>\n`
                + `${PHPEmoji} - for \`PHP\` - <@&834802358071722024>\n`
                + `${ChashEmoji} - for \`C#\` - <@&834764911137128474>\n`
                + `${CppEmoji} - for \`C++\`\ - <@&834764911153643520>\n`
                + `${CEmoji} - for \`C\` - <@&834802357929377793>\n`);

        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(JavaScriptEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(JavaEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(HTMLEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(CSSEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(PythonEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(PHPEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(ChashEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(CppEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(CEmoji);
 
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {

                if (reaction.emoji.name === JavaScriptEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(JavaScript);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === JavaEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(Java);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === HTMLEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(HTML);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === CSSEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(CSS);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === PythonEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(Python);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === PHPEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(PHP);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === ChashEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(Chash);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === CppEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(Cpp);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === CEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(C);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
 
        });
 
        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
 
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {

                if (reaction.emoji.name === JavaScriptEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(JavaScript);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === JavaEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(Java);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === HTMLEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(HTML);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === CSSEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(CSS);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === PythonEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(Python);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === PHPEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(PHP);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === ChashEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(Chash);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === CppEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(Cpp);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === CEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(C);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
 
}
```

thx to anyone that helps in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think its possible that if you could add some embeds fields

```
embeds : [{
 fields : [
 {
   name: you emoji name,
   value: the role mention
 }
 ]
}]
```

That could be available when user react to the emoji then iterate trough the field if emoji match the field name now you have the value

On messageReactionAdd event

```
if(reaction.message.embeds.length) {
// Check the embed is available
 if(reaction.message.embeds[0].fields.length) {
  //Now check whether the embed has fields
  // Finaly iterate the fields
  const fields = reaction.message.embeds[0].fields
  fields.forEach(async (field) => {
   if (field.name != reaction.emoji.name) return;
   if (field.name === reaction.emoji.name) {
     // What do you wanna do ? You can apply the role
     // First we need to get the id from the value <@&id>
     const role = field.value.replace(/[\\<>@#&!]/g, "") // get the id from mention regex
     // Add the role or check if already have a role if you want
     if (user.roles.cache.has(role)) {
       // User already have it
     } else {
       // User doesn't have a role
     }
    }
  })
 }
}
```

hope this help u out

Comment: Hey there Agiel, I asked for this 8 months ago, Discord.js buttons weren't a thing in v12 but since they are now in v13 I don't think I need this anymore. However, that is a good way to make reaction emojis work. Thank you for the suggestion.